# A question on vectors, pointers and iterators

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Guys, I have a midterm examination tomorrow, and I was looking over the sample paper, and I'm not sure about this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Let `v` be a `vector<Thingie*>`, so that each element `v[i]` contains a pointer to a `Thingie`. If `p` is a `vector<Thingie*>::iterator`, answer the following questions:

1. what type is `p`?
2. what type is `*p`?
3. what code provides the address of the actual `Thingie`?
4. what code provides the actual `Thingie`?

Comment: *Which* actual thingie? The one pointed to by the iterator or the one located at `v[i]` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> what type is `p`?

`p` is of type `vector<Thingie*>::iterator`, whatever type that happens to be.

> what type is `*p`?

`*p` is a `Thingie*&`; that is, it is a reference to the element in the vector at which the iterator points.

> what code provides the address of the actual `Thingie`?

`*p`, since the elements of the vector are pointers to the `Thingie`s, and `*p` gives a reference to the element in the vector.

> what code provides the actual `Thingie`?

`**p`; that is, you dereference the pointer obtained by `*p` to obtain the referent of the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

`p` is `vector::iterator`

`*p` is a pointer to a `Thingie`

`v[i]`

`*v[i]`